# What are FPC and Linecards?

Tags: juniper, switching

I am new to networking terms like this. Can somebody explain the difference between Linecards and FPCs? Are they the same or different?

I have been hearing these in multiple contexts and sometimes interchangeably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FPC's are similar to Linecards. When dealing with Juniper you will hear FPC more often. FPC's (Flexible PIC Concentrator) houses multiple PICs (Physical Interface Cards) which connect to the physical medium. Linecards are similar in that both FPCs and Linecards are inserted into a chassis device.

In Cisco, Linecards are just that. It's a card that's slotted into a chassis and provides a set of services to the chassis. For more info on FPCs, PICs, and Linecards see below:

[FPC](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/hardware/m40/m40-hwguide/html/overview-hardware6.html), [PIC](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/hardware/m40/m40-hwguide/html/overview-hardware5.html#1035509), [Cisco Line Cards](http://cisconokia.com/c/en/us/products/interfaces-modules/line-cards/index.html)

Comment: your link 'Cisco Line Cards' isn't working. Looks like a typo --> you mean  : http://cisco.com/c/en/us/products/interfaces-modules/line-cards/index.html